# I have an array with two types of object. I need to verify object class but

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a three classes: Entity, Student and Teacher.
All objects are saved in Entity array.
I need to verify class of `Entity[i]` item but when I try to virify I recieve an warning. Program is stopped and nothing goes. What to do?

```
class Entity {
     string param0;
}

class Student : Entity {
    string param1;
    //consturctor...
}

class Teacher : Entity {
    class string param2;
    //consturctor...
}

Entity[] entities = new Entity[5];
entities[0] = new Student("some string1");
entities[1] = new Teacher("some string2");
...
...
var es = entities[i] as Student; 
if (es.param1 != null) //here throw nullReferenceException
   Debug.Log(es.param1); 
else
   Debug.log(es.param2);
```

What i do incorect? How i can verify object class correctly?

Comment: But `i` is never defined... Please provide a *minimum working example* (something that compiles).

Comment: "The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Comment: `es.param1` should be `es` in the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting up your array with different types of `Entity`:

```
Entity[] entities = new Entity[5];
entities[0] = new Student("some string1");
entities[1] = new Teacher("some string2");
```

When you try to cast the entity at position 1 (i.e. the second item in the array) as a `Student`, the result will be `null`, as the entity is a `Teacher`:

```
var es = entities[i] as Student;
```

`es` is null at this point.

Instead, check the type, and then access the specific parameter once you know what type of entity you have.  One way to do this would be:

```
if (es is Student)
{
   Debug.Log((es as Student).param1); 
}
else if (es is Teacher)
{
   Debug.log((es as Teacher).param2);
}
else
{
    //some other entity
}
```